# DB2 Print analog

Tags: sql, db2

What's the DB2 Version of TSQL Print?

I've tried

```
Print 'TableName:X'
```

And

```
Select 'X' As 'TableName'
```

Comment: You can do it using sysibm.sysdummy1. Check my answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use sysibm.sysdummy1. It is a dummy table you can use to print constants values.
Print 'TableName:X' would be:

```
select 'TableName:X' from sysibm.sysdummy1;
```

And Select 'X' As 'TableName' would be:

```
select 'X' as TableName from sysibm.sysdummy1;
```

Similarly if you want to print the current date, etc you can use:

```
select current date FROM sysibm.sysdummy1;
```

Comment: This answer is old - values is much better than selecting from sysibm.sysdummy1 and the user is really asking for the echo command (@alpain's answer)

Comment: @Hogan, I do not have access to DB2 environment anymore, but is it possible to echo current date, etc or can we just echo hard-coded strings?

Comment: I'll test it tomorrow but I believe `select values(current date)` works

Comment: That was just what I needed. Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

Within the Command Line Processor I think ECHO is the most similar function to T-SQL's PRINT function.  See http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/db2luw/v9/index.jsp?topic=/com.ibm.db2.udb.admin.doc/doc/r0002006.htm.

For example:

```
ECHO 'Whatever you want printed';
```

Answer (score 2):

Would `VALUES 'Tablename=X'` work for you?

Answer (score -4):

Uggh...DB2.  My condolances.  ;-)

I don't think that there is a PRINT command.  Have a look [here](http://bytes.com/groups/ibm-db2/694237-print-value-during-execution-stored-procedure) for a similar thread.

Comment: You can print using sysibm.sysdummy1 table.

Comment: @C.Ross There is one, "echo". See Alpian's answer above.